# How to determine whether an address is an EOA or a contract address?

Tags: chaindata, eoa

I want to label each ethereum address whether it is EOA or not.

I'm thinking of the following method.

- Scan all transactions whose "to address" is the address to check. if the "input" of every transaction is null, then the address is EOA.

Is this OK? Or is there other methods that are more appropriate or efficient?

(For the data source of transactions, I use BigQuery public dataset.)

Comment: The schema of the BQ public dataset can be found here. https://ethereum-etl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/schema/

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I could not find the precise details on the data presented in the dataset. The links from [this](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/data-analytics/ethereum-bigquery-public-dataset-smart-contract-analytics) page did not work for me.

But the only correct way to find whether an account is an EOA is to actually check whether there is a code stored on this address. Looking at the transactions alone is *never* enough since there may be smart contracts with no transactions to them and there can also be EOAs with transactions with non-null data to their address (it is a noop, but might be used to send angry messages like [during the Poly network hack](https://twitter.com/JustDoingItBig/status/1425115724209655812?s=20)).

If you need to answer queries like "whether an address is an EOA" on-demand, the right way to do it would be to query [Infura](https://docs.infura.io/infura/networks/ethereum/json-rpc-methods/eth_getcode) or [Alchemy](https://docs.alchemy.com/alchemy/apis/ethereum/eth-getcode) for the code of the account and check whether it is empty.

Comment: Thank you. I understand. Actually, after rechecking the schema, I found the "countracts" table in the [schema](https://ethereum-etl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/schema/). This table would be the easiest way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Another way you can check if an address is an EOA or contract address is by calling [eth_getCode](https://docs.alchemy.com/reference/eth-getcode) with that address. This will return contract code if it's a contract and nothing if it's a wallet. Here's an example of an eth_getCode call with a contract and with a wallet address:

[0x Contract Address](https://composer.alchemy.com?share=eJyVmE1TGzkQhv_LzxwCOFnMzXjjJVW74AKSy1bKJc_07Sk00qykifGm_O.RjI2R1N2yc4Gq7ud99dXSyPo5KNaiUoPrAbj14GxQ_3_6vG9cpZUdXP.7c.BDyBZ8XshiDfV2vgI3thbckxHKLsFYr5JiATLLvJ6RTk.6GdRYSr0RqgDaKWFyTjdCdgzTpRjJ_fwDTpTCiYzPAeF8uqGLopvHByigahzXKwKkPA3814J1M7GthXVgxqr8k_4iR1KutqpbKRz0yzVZC7UiZ4.Ecn6fX6BouzFlzN6Z0KnQddM6eBCmcttAHcdDRQmLdjV3RhRwI3XxfLO9FbYr5jcpA_Q97tp6ASbrskcYn4mQkpb3GUYVlAMtDoHQw2.cuSgK3aqo0qJwyi_6caCBpplUVcQDO4QQ150sX8oU3UcRrSu1EDY8BKJwyvsKr2pfRX_JdLhhhlN9tWDuGzCim0feAmGp3xLgtrJOm7BUk0SqWQk7M1V03EVhxIPbn1qp4j1Baci9QCR5LVkaKM3piXOPTHP6oNInXf1mx8LAp3tnx8rihP9El8RC9VGCnlbSH9H45CXTrP5vvWLFfY5Q0hqOnhmtlxjfhQn_QWtHL9chQ6ge.YYRKxg7LHtPEbpgfW62.Yp1LfgP3xdVwgs2O8Kf1MKuAn6njURxrBV6_jCS9_nrNWuzI.Iu_82a9XljTnKy_zk5xfHAEs5fVSHhpDVnySOux9Y5w3LO_zPk0BXGFGGn_HHnGAdSnuFXj6tDCjrmxVYRSaVua9_EJ9LD9RBO_Vq8_A_q7u6LU4AZGPydJxHkU6lKrVLlLpiyCjb95O6O3kSTJAktJ_MVM1Cl70iwaTgPlkxdGwSm00YRyMVopwstv.mff.FllsqmautbeBAb_jbMAJRH3uCYOipLQh.nkUO1QqIuhLi2abRxUH5Wzmxn.sKL7kwkgny2qsCF_hZN6dbXr3X_3k7WS5oN1f1txvfDTxzxQ5nKMmo71eZ_o6LGyXSin0qtTXqFjuOJ4m76RHc1TGDNo5DRpSyMYhqTJOVHNdFSQlqUZDrR99ORc6AAzqN.x2Dku1yifGxEfVicWBinQl1lb7Us.T5Zkn0m07E_9I6UUSLUKHBz6X99QXJwx.FU0YC.aSe3pTieKn6gsy2MhrQB36L.VUmMA6ViXbfvu4FGikMwZC0IU6wzW5MBIo_2rv0Ly..gS3HsnKkW.s0lXGsGCD36Z4rdC0IgDKOYTt4UgiBml_mBFYUx78sTwV0Mk4b74pBpQg_NFLvbFfP1zHOcY7ZTiMAu.i_rD3OhcgOLy3khK1AOf8KJJNLatbhMJX3s9ftZt0822jwPrj_8vTnfiRr.iG6EEfW3zrV7jB58eIHheXkxvBp9.OO8vLy4OL8aXQw.lWIpPsKihPPl8NNotByOrvqGfWG6wffXX6vLOIo-)

[Vitalik's Wallet Address](https://composer.alchemy.com?share=eJyVmE1PIzkQhv9LnznAZtECtyRDlpF2IQJmLqtR5O6uJC3cdq.tnpAZ8d.H7oTgjyoncwGp6nlff5Xdjn8W1Zo1orgpwKyLs6K1.2T90JlGCl3c.Pez_M54DzbPeLWGdrtYgRlrDeZZMaGXoLRVcVYCzzJvZ6jTs3wBMeZcbpioAHeKmJzThHHHEF0KkZzPv2BYzQzL_BwQyscNnVVuHh_hgqYzVK8QEPNU8H8P2szZtmXagBqL_hPeRYrEXHXT9pwZGJZrumZihc4eiuX8bl_h6t2YMmYfjO9UybbrDTwy1Zitpw7jvqKGsl8tjGIVTLisXibbO6ZdMb9LCSDvcd_3Jaisyx4hfKaMc1w_ZAiVVw642Ad8D7txF6yqZC_CSgvCMV_6cSQDjTOxqgoHdgglnDtZPtcxuo8mtGxEybR.CAThmLcV3rS2iv5m8XD9DKX6okE9dKCYm0faIsFivyXAXaONVH6pRolYs2J6rprguAvCCQ9mf2rFio8EpkH3ApKktWhpJGlKj5x7aJrSe5U_dfWbHQsBn_6dHSuJI.5TWSMLNUQRetZwe0SnJy_aJvX.yBUpHnKIEtdQ9FxJuUzxXRjhH6U0_HIdMojqyW4YtoKxSWUfKUTnrc9kO6yYa8F__D6LGl5TsyP8SS3sKuB32ogUx1rBpy9F8j5DvWZtdkTeZb9Zsz7vzElOej8npzgeWMT5i6g4nLTmJHnE9dg6Z1jKeX_GHLpCmCbYKX7UOUaBmKf.1aPqEIOOeZFVhFKx29o2YYn4cD2EY75lr.aDKt19cQYwB5V_51Ek8WlEI1axcheMWQGbYXJ3R2_kiZKIlpLRijmI2nbE2zSUB0nGrl0CxtOGEYmLkkZWkn_1P..CyyyWjdXatvDINvhtmAAwj7zBMXVQlog_zCcOzSoRuVDC9V0nlYH6Vhi1ndsLb3JnQpHEZyuqtFDfozHd2.rVxt7b0XqJs756uM3YftiJQ34oY1lCrWdSPWxE0DiajvQzLqWKr9BhPFLcz57xrvqJVPPEeHAp86MpnZIoZUc1lZxDXJRoOtIP05FzwADKY3jHIOS7XKR86lh7WJxQGKZ8XaPvJK.tPlmifUbTod73DpRBwtcIMAtuf31BdHCH8VjRgb1pR7elMB4rvidnmx.1aQW2RfurEhlHkgp1bt_7gQaKQ9BnNTBVrTNbkwACj75t7QvLD7ClODZGNaV9c.HXmgB8j_GZYveC4An9aEpHbwpeMGWX8YEVhFPelmcCu1hKKuqLg6YRPXSc7W5XxNczz1GO2U4lROpi.5J6P_crN1COFhVvQJj0E44kE61es1EsGWJv387cPtlI9VLcnL_.Od_zNv0R3THF2q.O1T1GF_ev4.Ly6vyC.fVpdH01urwor8rbi4vpn6NrOL_cXk5Gf1xeM5heT4aGbWGa4tvbL5hCN8s-)

Comment: This technically does not determine if an address is an EOA. It may be a contract address with no bytecode deployed to it yet.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [Alchemy SDK](https://docs.alchemy.com/reference/alchemy-sdk-quickstart) ( v 2.9.2 or up ) you can just use the method called [`isContractAddress`](https://docs.alchemy.com/reference/iscontractaddress-sdk) to check if an address is a contract or not.

You can find the docs for it [here](https://docs.alchemy.com/reference/iscontractaddress-sdk)

It's super simple to use as it just accepts an address and returns a boolean value indicating if it is a contract or not. Here's a simple script:

```js
// Imports the Alchemy SDK
const { Alchemy, Network } = require("alchemy-sdk");

// Configures the Alchemy SDK
const config = {
    apiKey: "demo", // Replace with your API key
    network: Network.ETH_MAINNET, // Replace with your network
};

// Creates an Alchemy object instance with the config to use for making requests
const alchemy = new Alchemy(config);

const main = async () => {
    const result = await alchemy.core.isContractAddress("0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2"); // Wrapped ETH address

    // Logging the response to the console
    console.log(result)
}

main();
```

If you want to do it with pure JSON-RPC APIs then querying [`eth_getCode`](https://docs.alchemy.com/reference/sdk-getcode) and checking its output would be the right approach. An empty output ( `0x` ) would mean an EOA otherwise a contract.